# Microsoft Graph API - Updating password

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API sample project. I am able to login fine.

I am trying to update the password of the user that is logged in using the following code:

```cs
public async Task<bool> UpdatePassword(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string newPassword)
{
    User me = await graphClient.Me.Request().UpdateAsync(new User
    {
        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            Password = newPassword,
            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
        },
    });
    return true;
}
```

When I execute the code, I get the following error:

```cs
{
  Status: 500
  Message: "No offeractions were provided for validating consent."
  Internal error: "empty offerActions array."
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing incorrectly?

I gave access to everything "Users" related via the App Registration Portal at `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a baked-in `ChangePassword()` function that you'll want to use for this:

```cs
await graphClient.Me.ChangePassword("current-pwd, "new-pwd").Request().PostAsync();
```

Comment: The code you originally posted is really password reset code - where an admin resets/changes another user's password.  Please use Marc's suggestion, which is designed for the signed-in user to change their own password (by providing their old password and new password).  For now, this requires granting the app Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission.